# Show active class if page is active in PHP with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get my navigation from an array and show an **active class** if the page is active. Everything is working but i don't get how i can make the page active with the class. Here is a little bit of my code:

```
foreach($navlinks as $key => $value){
    if ($value === $key){
        echo '<li class="active"><a href="'.$key.'.php">'.$value.'</a>';
        }else {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $key . '.php">' . $value . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much

EDIT:

My Array:

```
$navlinks = array ('index' => 'Home', 'over-ons' => 'Over ons', 'contact' => 'Contact');
```

EXAMPLE:

```html
 <li class="active"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: "i don't get how i can make the page active with the class" What do you mean?

Comment: Please tell me what $key variable contain and the $value please show little bit more of code what the variable contain

Comment: Edited my post with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost there.  You just need to fix the comparison to determine the current page.  You may need to do something like

```
$current_page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);  // trim off the leading slash
$current_page = str_replace('.php', '', $current_page);  // trim off the extension

foreach ($navlinks as $key => $value) {
    if ( $current_page == $key ) {
         ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```